# How can I pop, peek and get the size?

Tags: java, generics

I have this piece of code where I am actually pushing element into the stack and I did make it but if I want to pop, peek and get the size of the stack afterwards how it should be actually done? Anyone who can provide help I can say thanks a lot for your time.

```
public class MyGenericsStack<T extends Object> {
 
    private int stackSize;
    private T[] stackArr;
    private int top;
     
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyGenericsStack(int size) {
        this.stackSize = size;
        this.stackArr = (T[]) new Object[stackSize];
        this.top = -1;
    }
 
    public void push(T entry){
        if(this.isStackFull()){
            System.out.println(("Stack is full. It is increased now"));
            this.increaseStackCapacity();
        }
        System.out.println("Add it: "+entry);
        this.stackArr[++top] = entry;
    }
 
    public T pop() throws Exception {
        if(this.isStackEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Stack is empty. You can't remove element.");
        }
        T entry = this.stackArr[top--];
        System.out.println("Removed: "+entry);
        return entry;
    }
     
    public T peek() {
        return stackArr[top];
    }
 
    private void increaseStackCapacity(){
         
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] newStack = (T[]) new Object[this.stackSize*2];
        for(int i=0;i<stackSize;i++){
            newStack[i] = this.stackArr[i];
        }
        this.stackArr = newStack;
        this.stackSize = this.stackSize*2;
    }
     
    public boolean isStackEmpty() {
        return (top == -1);
    }
 
    public boolean isStackFull() {
        return (top == stackSize - 1);
    } 
     
    public static void main(String a[]){
        MyGenericsStack<String> Stack = new MyGenericsStack<String>(4);
        Stack.push("kkk");
        Stack.push("sss");
        Stack.push("ppp");
        Stack.push("aaa"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `Stack.pop()` and `Stack.peek()` pop and peek respectively. You can't get the size without adding another method that provides that. What exactly are you having problems with? Adding the method or actually just calling them?

Comment: So actually also adding the method and calling as well, but in this case as you can see I am only pushing elements into the stack im trying to call it as well for the pop and peek.

Comment: Btw: it's bad coding style to throw generic Exceptions, as it makes good exception handling almost impossible. There is `EmptyStackException` you could use. It's also a runtime Exception, so you don't need to declare it in your method signature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think is wrong with your `pop` abd `peek` methods, they look fine to me.

To get the size, you can write a method returning `this.top + 1` - `this.top` holds the last index in the array that was filled, so adding 1 to it will give you the amount of elements stored in the internal array.

```
public int size() {
    return this.top + 1;
}
```

Comment: And how do I call it in main in this case.

Comment: erm.... same as any other method?  `myStackObject.size();`

Comment: u mean to call just his way in main?

Comment: As with anny object, you need to instanciate a new instance to work with, then you can call any method on it. It's how Java objects work. I do get the feeling you lack the overal idea of how object oriented programming works. In this case, please do a few tutorials first.